# Как узнать текущий URl а не URL обработчика в PHP

Tags: php

Как можно вывести текущий урл страницы если я использую обработчик?

То есть если я нахожусь на странице likes и запрашиваю $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] при открытии страницы всё в порядке, скрипт выдаёт корректно /likes.php

Но как только я на этой странице нажимаю пагинацию и по аякс отправляю данные в обработчик, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] показывает адрес обработчика /filter.php хотя в браузере адрес страницы https://.../likes.php

Как можно узнать адрес страницы, а не адрес обработчика?

Comment: передавайте её параметром или в заголовках

Comment: А есть другие варианты? Неужели в php невозможно узнать урл который в браузере

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` смотрите, но не уверен что там всегда будет то что вам надо, поэтому надёжней передавать самому ссылку

Comment: php не знает ни про какой браузер. Он просто отдает данные получив запрос. Куда эти данные выведутся - в браузер, в консоль, в девнулл - ему все равно.